# Add file upload to form and send via email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, forms

I created a simple contact form and now trying to add feature where user can attach a file and sent it via email.

I have added the upload field to my `.phtml` file but I am not sure how to attach the file and sent it. Can anyone help me a bit, this is the last step but a bit too much for me...

Here is what I have so far:

> app/etc/modules/Recruitment_SimpleContact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Recruitment_SimpleContact>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Recruitment_SimpleContact>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Recruitment/SimpleContact/controllers/IndexController.php

```
    <?php

    class Recruitment_SimpleContact_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            //Get current layout state
            $this->loadLayout();

           $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
                'recruitment.simple_contact',
                array(
                    'template' => 'recruitment/simple_contact.phtml'
                )
            );

           $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
            //$this->getLayout()->getBlock('right')->insert($block, 'catalog.compare.sidebar', true);

           $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');

           $this->renderLayout();
        }


                public function sendemailAction() {

                    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
                    $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
                    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
                    $jobRole = $this->getRequest()->getParam('job_role');
                    $telephoneNumber = $this->getRequest()->getParam('telephone_number');
                                    $comment = $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment');
                    $body1 = "Name: " .$name ."\r\n";
                    $body2 = "Job Role " .$jobRole ."\r\n";
                    $body3 = "Telephone: " .$telephoneNumber ."\r\n";
                                    $body4 = "Additional Comments: " .$comment ."\r\n";
                    $body = $body1.' '.$body2.' '.$body3.' '.$body4.' ' ;

                    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                    $mail->setBodyText($body);
                    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
                    $mail->addTo('myemail@emial.com');
                    $mail->setSubject('Recruitment enquiries');
                    try {
                        $mail->send();
                    }
                    catch(Exception $ex) {
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email. Please check that the details you have entered are correct.');
                    }
                    //Redirect back to index action of (this) recruitment-simplecontact controller
                    $this->_redirect('recruitment-simplecontact/');
                }
    }

    ?>
```

> app/code/local/Recruitment/SimpleContact/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Recruitment_SimpleContact>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Recruitment_SimpleContact>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <RandomRouter2>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Recruitment_SimpleContact</module>
                    <frontName>recruitment-simplecontact</frontName>
                </args>
            </RandomRouter2>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app/design/frontend/default/default/template/recruitment/simple_contact.phtml

```
        <div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
        <div class="page-title">
            <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Recruitment Contact') ?></h1>
        </div>

        <form id="contactForm" name="simple_contact_form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('recruitment-simplecontact/') ?>index/sendemail" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                      <div class="fieldset">
                        <fieldset class="group-select">
                            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
                            <ul>
                            <li class="fields">
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="name">Name <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />

                                        <input name="name" id="name" title="Name" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="email">Email <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                        <input name="email" id="email" title="Email" value="" class="required-entry input-text validate-email" type="text" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="job_role">Job role<span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                        <input name="job_role" id="job_role" title="Job Role" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="telephone_number">Telephone Number <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                        <input name="telephone_number" id="telephone_number" title="Telephone Number" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="clear"></div>

                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="comment">Comment</label><br />

                                        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="Comment" class="required-entry input-text" style="height:100px;" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for='uploaded_file'>Select A File To Upload:</label>

                                        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
                                    </div>
                            </li>

                            </ul>
                        </fieldset>
                        </div>


            <div class="button-set">
                <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
                <button style="float: right; margin-bottom: 10px;" class="button" type="submit"><span>Submit <br></span></button>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

All I need is a simple file attachment to this form, seems straight forward but just exceeds my capability.

Can someone help me add a file attachment to this form and sent via email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using something like this:

```
try {
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

        $text = array();
        foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
            if ($key == 'hideit' || $key == 'redirect_to') {
                continue;
            }
            if (is_array($val)) {
                $val = implode(', ', $val);
            }
            $text[] = "$key: $val";
        }

        $vars['form_text'] = implode("\n", $text);

        $transactionalEmail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId));

        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $val) {
            if ($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name']) {
                foreach($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'] as $keyName => $fileName){
                    $transactionalEmail
                        ->getMail()
                        ->createAttachment(
                            file_get_contents($fileName),
                            Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                            Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                            Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                            $_FILES[$key]['name'][$keyName]
                        );
                }
            }
        }
        $transactionalEmail->sendTransactional($templateId, $senderEmail, 'recipient@email.com', 'Recipient Name', $vars, $storeId);

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Message sent.'));
    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Message not sent.'));
    }
```

But this uses an email template from transactional emails section. The `$vars` variable are all the values from that were filled in form fields. This code should be added to ***sendEmailAction()***. This code is for multiple attachment files. For single attachment file you have to change this part:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $val) {
      if ($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name']) {
           foreach($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'] as $keyName => $fileName){
             $transactionalEmail
                  ->getMail()
                 ->createAttachment(
                     file_get_contents($fileName),
                      Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                      Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                      Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                      $_FILES[$key]['name'][$keyName]
                  );
            }
       }
 }
```

with this:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $val) {
            if ($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name']) {
                $transactionalEmail
                    ->getMail()
                    ->createAttachment(
                        file_get_contents($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name']),
                        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                        $_FILES[$key]['name']
                    );
            }
        }
```

But be careful, if the attachment is multiple you have to set the name of the field like an array, like this:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" multiple >
```

**EDIT:**

You have to go to **System->Transactional Emails** to create a new e-mail template (you have to search on web on how to do that if you don't know yet), after that you should change your ***sendemail()*** method with this:

```
public function sendemailAction()
{
    // Fetch submitted params
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    $templateId = 1; //the id of the created template

    // Sender
    $sender['name'] = 'John Doe'; 
    $sender['email'] = 'owner@example.com'; 

    // Recepient
    $recipientEmail = 'youremail@email.com'; //the email where you want to receive the emails
    $recipientName = 'John Doe'; //enter recipient email you want
    $vars = $params; //the values from the form fields

    try {
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

        $text = array();
        foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
            if ($key == 'hideit' || $key == 'redirect_to') {
                continue;
            }
            if (is_array($val)) {
                $val = implode(', ', $val);
            }
            $text[] = "$key: $val";
        }
        $vars['form_text'] = implode("\n", $text);

        $transactionalEmail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId));

        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $val) {
            if ($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name']) {
                $transactionalEmail
                    ->getMail()
                    ->createAttachment(
                        file_get_contents($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name']),
                        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                        $_FILES[$key]['name']
                    );
            }
        }

        $transactionalEmail->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recipientEmail, $recipientName, $vars, $storeId);

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Message sent.'));
    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Message not sent.'));
    }
   $this->_redirect('/');
}
```

This works for me and should work for you, hope it helps.

**EDIT 2**
In the e-mail template you have to make a template that you want to receive on the email. Something like this:

```
<h1>New Order</h1>

<p>Name: {{var name}}</p>
<p>Name: {{var email}}</p>
<p>Name: {{var job_role}}</p>
<p>Name: {{var telephone_number}}</p>
<p>Name: {{var message}}</p>
```

**Very important: between `{{ }}` you should put the word *var* and followed by the exactly field name**

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This look more complicated then my code :D How would I merge those to work? I only need an simple attachment to be added to my form :/

Comment: I've edited my answer, take a look and let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks for coming back! I have updated my IndexController.php with your code but now, when I submit the order the page goes blank (There is nothing in it). Also, what should I include in my email template? Or can it be empty?

Comment: Check my updated question with the errors from logs.

Comment: I've edited sendemail method you should see if it works. You have to chenge the code were I left comments if you want this to work. I forgot to add a redirect after email sends. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi mate. I get redirected to home page now, however, the email is not being sent... See my updated question with new error. Sorry for making this difficult for you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the email template. Are you sure you set the correct template ID? Try to use a default Magento template and just edit the var names. The code looks like is working but something is wrong with your template.

Comment: Hi there, I have changed the templateid to "`1`" and changed the var in that template. Same again... `exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.' in /domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:374`

Comment: You have to put a template id that exists in transactional emails section. Just go to System->Transactional Emails and get a correct ID from there.

Comment: I have done. The template ID "49" would be the new one I have created, however that did't work, so I used one already created by Magento with id "`1`", however that didn't work either. I have a bounty on that question of +50 so if I get it working it will be all yours :D

Comment: I found what I did wrong in my code. Change this line: $sender = 'owner@example.com'; with this $sender['name'] = 'John Doe'; $sender['email'] = 'owner@example.com'; I've edited my answer.

Comment: It's working! :D That's great! Thank you. I can only award the bounty in 22 hours so I will do that. Well deserved for the time and effort you put into this!

Comment: I'm so glad that it's working and I could help you, have a nice day!